# Choices.js and LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I am trying to use the choice.js library inside a lightning component handling select HTML Element.

I think there might be a conflict with the LockerService but there is no error displayed on the page or in the HTML.

Is there a way to know if this library is LockerService compliant ?

[Choices.js](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices)

Comment: [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Comment: @glis this doesn't answer the question and as Christophe Coenraets said in his article it's a non- exhaustive list of libraries

Comment: @Nordine Hammache, which is why I posted Possible duplicate of crmprogdev's post which answers this question perfectly imo

Comment: @glis well except the "strict-mode" mention it actually doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @glls as Nordine Hammache I think the question you show as dupe does only provide a general answer and isn't fully sufficient. I think it's worth to keep questions regarding each single paticular JS lib and we don't need to limit ourselves to the few libs we have a greenlight on. It doesn't do harm if we have several questions regarding even rarely used js libs. It can only be helpful for all of us. Therefore I vote to reopen.

Comment: @NordineHammache can you vote to reopen? I did already.

Comment: @glls maybe it's even worth to discuss this on meta if we want a wide open or closed attitude towards the huge number of possible js libs. A collection of verification questions that a lib works in version x in season y of Salesforce would be a great value. I would argue for One question per lib. Version re-checks should be aggregated.

Comment: there already exists a post with steps to verifying if a library is locker service compliant, see [Is there any way to validate a third party JavaScript library against Lightning LockerService?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164607/is-there-any-way-to-validate-a-third-party-javascript-library-against-lightning/169220).