# LWC - catch block is always getting executed in loadscript LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

My static resource

[image: My static resource]

Trying to load this script using loadscript. Below is my code...

```
    import { api,track,LightningElement } from 'lwc';
        import {
            loadScript
        } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
        import instascan from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/instascan';


    export default class QRCodeScanner extends LightningElement {
        @track instascanInitialized = false;

        renderedCallback() {
                if(this.instascanInitialized){
                    return;
                }
                this.instascanInitialized = true;
                loadScript(this, instascan)
                    .then(() => { 
                        console.log('hii then'+then);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('hii error' +error);
                    });
            }
  }
```

Always getting the same thing in the console

[image: Chrome Console tab]

According to the console the catch block is getting executed. But in the network tab I see the static resource is been initialized properly!

[image: Chrome Network tab]

Please let me know why am I getting this error even if the static resource is been loaded and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with your implementation.

Instascan is not compliant with Locker service. A quick read from this article - [Is there any way to validate a third party JavaScript library against Lightning LockerService?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164607/is-there-any-way-to-validate-a-third-party-javascript-library-against-lightning), and checking instascan library, below will be observations:

- It has ***new function***
- It has ***eval()*** usage
- It does not have **global use strict**

Comparatively [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) is locker service compliant and will have no problem loading in LWC.

Comment: can you suggest a library which is compliant with the locker service and can be used for QR code scanning?

Comment: check quaggajs! i am trying to build the scanner component in salesforce through it.